# Could someone point out the type instability in my code?

Tags: types, julia

I am doing some interval computations using the library [ValidatedNumerics](https://github.com/dpsanders/ValidatedNumerics.jl) and I am trying to optimize my code. I define the following:

```
using ValidatedNumerics

immutable Vector2D{T}
  x::Complex{ValidatedNumerics.Interval{T}}
  y::Complex{ValidatedNumerics.Interval{T}}
end

function F(x::Complex{ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}},y::Complex{ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}})
  g = 3(1+(1+x+y)^2)/4
  Vector2D{BigFloat}(x + 2y + g,y + g)
end
```

Then using the following gives the correct unswer

```
x = @biginterval(1+1im)

F(x,x)
```

However, when I type:

```
@code_warntype F(x,x)
```

I get:

```
Variables:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  #self#::#F                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  x::Complex{ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  y::Complex{ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  g::Complex{T<:Real}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

Body:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
  begin                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      # meta: location operators.jl + 138                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
      # meta: location complex.jl + 162                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      SSAValue(0) = (Core.getfield)(x::Complex{ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}},:re)::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}                                                                                                                                       
      SSAValue(2) = $(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for +(::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, ::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}), :(Base.+), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}(::BigFloat, ::BigFloat), ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for _convert_rounding(::Type{BigFloat}, ::Int64, ::RoundingMode{:Down}), :(Base.Rounding._convert_rounding), BigFloat, 1, :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundDown)))), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for _convert_rounding(::Type{BigFloat}, ::Int64, ::RoundingMode{:Up}), :(Base.Rounding._convert_rounding), BigFloat, 1, :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundUp))))))), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}(::BigFloat, ::BigFloat), ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Down}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(0),:lo)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundDown)))), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Up}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(0),:hi)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundUp)))))))))                                                                                                                                                                                             
      SSAValue(1) = (Core.getfield)(x::Complex{ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}},:im)::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}                                                                                                                                       
      # meta: pop location                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
      SSAValue(7) = $(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}(::BigFloat, ::BigFloat), ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Down}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(2),:lo)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundDown)))), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Up}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(2),:hi)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundUp))))))                                     
      SSAValue(8) = $(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}(::BigFloat, ::BigFloat), ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Down}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(1),:lo)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundDown)))), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Up}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(1),:hi)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundUp))))))                                     
      # meta: location complex.jl + 125                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
      SSAValue(5) = $(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for +(::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, ::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}), :(Base.+), SSAValue(7), :((Core.getfield)(y,:re)::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat})))                                       
      SSAValue(4) = $(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for +(::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, ::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}), :(Base.+), SSAValue(8), :((Core.getfield)(y,:im)::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat})))                                       
      # meta: pop location
      SSAValue(6) = $(Expr(:new, Complex{ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}}, :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}(::BigFloat, ::BigFloat), ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Down}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(5),:lo)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundDown)))), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Up}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(5),:hi)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundUp))))))), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}(::BigFloat, ::BigFloat), ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Down}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(4),:lo)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundDown)))), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Up}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(4),:hi)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundUp)))))))))
      # meta: pop location
      SSAValue(9) = (3 * (1 + (Core._apply)(Base.^,$(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for promote(::Complex{ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}}, ::Complex{Int64}), :(Base.promote), SSAValue(6), :($(Expr(:new, Complex{Int64}, 2, 0))))))::Complex{T<:Real})::Complex{T<:Real})::Complex{T<:Real}
      g::Complex{T<:Real} = (Base.Complex)(((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(9),:re)::Real / 4)::Any,((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(9),:im)::Real / 4)::Any)::Complex{T<:Real} # line 3:
      # meta: location complex.jl * 170
      SSAValue(11) = (Core.getfield)(y::Complex{ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}},:re)::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}
      SSAValue(12) = $(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for *(::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, ::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}), :(Base.*), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}(::BigFloat, ::BigFloat), ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for _convert_rounding(::Type{BigFloat}, ::Int64, ::RoundingMode{:Down}), :(Base.Rounding._convert_rounding), BigFloat, 2, :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundDown)))), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for _convert_rounding(::Type{BigFloat}, ::Int64, ::RoundingMode{:Up}), :(Base.Rounding._convert_rounding), BigFloat, 2, :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundUp))))))), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}(::BigFloat, ::BigFloat), ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Down}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(11),:lo)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundDown)))), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Up}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(11),:hi)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundUp)))))))))
      SSAValue(10) = (Core.getfield)(y::Complex{ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}},:im)::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}
      SSAValue(13) = $(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for *(::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, ::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}), :(Base.*), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}(::BigFloat, ::BigFloat), ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for _convert_rounding(::Type{BigFloat}, ::Int64, ::RoundingMode{:Down}), :(Base.Rounding._convert_rounding), BigFloat, 2, :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundDown)))), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for _convert_rounding(::Type{BigFloat}, ::Int64, ::RoundingMode{:Up}), :(Base.Rounding._convert_rounding), BigFloat, 2, :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundUp))))))), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}(::BigFloat, ::BigFloat), ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Down}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(10),:lo)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundDown)))), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Up}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(10),:hi)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundUp)))))))))
      # meta: pop location
      SSAValue(22) = $(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}(::BigFloat, ::BigFloat), ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Down}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(12),:lo)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundDown)))), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Up}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(12),:hi)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundUp))))))
      SSAValue(23) = $(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}(::BigFloat, ::BigFloat), ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Down}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(13),:lo)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundDown)))), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Up}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(13),:hi)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundUp))))))
      # meta: location operators.jl + 138
      # meta: location complex.jl + 125
      SSAValue(16) = $(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for +(::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, ::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}), :(Base.+), :((Core.getfield)(x,:re)::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}), SSAValue(22)))
      SSAValue(15) = $(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for +(::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, ::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}), :(Base.+), :((Core.getfield)(x,:im)::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}), SSAValue(23)))
      # meta: pop location
      SSAValue(19) = $(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}(::BigFloat, ::BigFloat), ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Down}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(16),:lo)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundDown)))), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Up}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(16),:hi)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundUp))))))
      SSAValue(20) = $(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}(::BigFloat, ::BigFloat), ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}, :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Down}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(15),:lo)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundDown)))), :($(Expr(:invoke, LambdaInfo for BigFloat(::BigFloat, ::RoundingMode{:Up}), BigFloat, :((Core.getfield)(SSAValue(15),:hi)::BigFloat), :(ValidatedNumerics.RoundUp))))))
      SSAValue(18) = (Base.Complex)((SSAValue(19) + (Core.getfield)(g::Complex{T<:Real},:re)::Real)::Any,(SSAValue(20) + (Core.getfield)(g::Complex{T<:Real},:im)::Real)::Any)::Complex{T<:Real}
      # meta: pop location
      SSAValue(21) = (Base.Complex)(((Core.getfield)(y::Complex{ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}},:re)::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat} + (Core.getfield)(g::Complex{T<:Real},:re)::Real)::Any,((Core.getfield)(y::Complex{ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}},:im)::ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat} + (Core.getfield)(g::Complex{T<:Real},:im)::Real)::Any)::Complex{T<:Real}
      return $(Expr(:new, Vector2D{BigFloat}, :($(Expr(:new, Complex{ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}}, :((Base.convert)(ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat},(Core.getfield)(SSAValue(18),:re)::Real)), :((Base.convert)(ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat},(Core.getfield)(SSAValue(18),:im)::Real))))), :($(Expr(:new, Complex{ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}}, :((Base.convert)(ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat},(Core.getfield)(SSAValue(21),:re)::Real)), :((Base.convert)(ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat},(Core.getfield)(SSAValue(21),:im)::Real)))))))
  end::Vector2D{BigFloat}
```

In that, the following are red:

```
::Complex{T<:Real} 
::Real
::Any
```

Does this actually mean that my definition is type unstable? How can I fix that?

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here; there does seem to be something that Julia can't figure out (seems to be in the `promotion` in `SSA(9)` if you check in the REPL, where there is colour highlighting of the type-unstable computations). But I would expect that the time penalty due to the type instability is small compared to the running time of manipulating `BigFloat` `Interval`s in any case! Type instability only matters if you are looking to improve performance and that is actually a significant part of the running time.

Comment: Note that you can write just `Interval`, instead of `ValidatedNumerics.Interval`. You could also parameterize the function `F`, instead of using explicit types.

Comment: I am trying to parametrize F but I am not quite sure how to work with complex numbers. I would expect that Complex is supertype of Real but it is not. I am reading about this. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @tst you need to do something like: `F{T<:Real}(x::Complex{Interval{T}}, y::Complex{Interval{T}})`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @David Sanders noted `SSAValue(9)` is the source of the problem for `F`. Digging further (quite a bit of digging follows), it is the `^2` which messes the type inference. The type signature of the arguments to `^` are

```
Complex{ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}}, Int64
```

which calls `^(Complex,Complex)` after converting `2` to `Complex{Int64}(2,0)`. In turn, `^(Complex,Complex)` promoted the `Complex{Int64}` into a `Complex{ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}}`. Now, we are getting to some actual computation in `^(T<:Complex,T<:Complex)` in `complex.jl:506`.
Here is a code snippet, with some lines marked:

```
function ^{T<:Complex}(z::T, p::T)
    if isinteger(p)
        rp = real(p)        # <---------- (1)
        if rp < 0
            return power_by_squaring(inv(float(z)), convert(Integer, -rp))
        else
            return power_by_squaring(float(z), convert(Integer, rp))
        end
    end
    pr, pim = reim(p)
    zr, zi = reim(z)
    r = abs(z)            # <---------- (*)
    rp = r^pr             # <---------- (2)
    theta = atan2(zi, zr)
```

This function has two execution branches, the first, when the power is an integer, and the second when it isn't. Both branches use the `rp` variable and assign it to different types, making `rp`'s type inferenced to Any. A second problem is the line marked `(*)`. Note this line does not actually get executed in the calculation because the power is an integer. If it was executed, the problems wouldn't stay in the type-inference level but become a stack overflow.

`abs(z)` when `z` is Complex{T} in `(*)` calls `hypot(T,T)` on the real and imaginary parts. These in turn calls `sqrt(float(T))` (for Pythagoras' theorem). This is defined in `complex.jl:320` as:

```
sqrt(z::Complex) = sqrt(float(z))
```

Since `float(Complex{ValidatedNumerics.Interval{BigFloat}})` is `Complex{ValidatedNumerics.Interval{Float64}}`, this still calls `sqrt(Complex)` causing a loop and a stackoverflow (not this site's name this time). This self-loop also causes a `Union{}` type-inference which causes the calling function to fail type-inference too.

In summary, there is room for more careful implementation and testing of `complex.jl`.

This is all the digging I have time for now, but if clarification or fixes are needed, comments would be welcome.

To practically, solve the problem, an explicit type-assertion with `::` on the result of `^` might resolve the problem with `F`.

Comment: I changed the definition of F by setting
    g = 3(1+(1+x+y)*(1+x+y))/4
this seems to solve my problems

Comment: Yes, I don't get anything red now, so I assume it is fixed. Right?

Comment: Yes. Works here too. Now the issue is fixing the underlying problem. Maybe changing definition of `float(Complex{T})` to return a vanilla Float64 is enough. But care is needed and the place for this is a github issue.

Comment: I am actually confused with complex numbers. I can barely understand types in julia and it seems that Complex is not a supertype of Real as I would expect and I am not sure how to work with them. What I do is mostly trial and error.

Comment: Complex in julia is currently implemented as a "wrapper" to pairs of values of the same type (which must be a subtype of Real). This gives the flexibility to plug-in different version of reals, according to the needed precision and implementation of real numbers and still get the correct complex arithmetic. Your example proves this works with Interval as a plug-in. It is actually a beautiful example of the strengths of the julia language. Generating both efficient and clean code even though it combines packages from different sources.

Comment: That was quite some detective work @Dan, thanks! I'll look at modifying the source when I have a moment.

Comment: I have reported the issue at https://github.com/dpsanders/ValidatedNumerics.jl/issues/173. Please feel free to open issues there for any more bugs or issues with the package.

Comment: Note that the `float` function is for converting "pieces of objects" to floats, not for conversion to a float. E.g. `float(3 + 4im)` (with argument of type `Complex{Int}`) gives `3.0 + 4.0im` (with result of type `Complex{Float}`).

Comment: OK, apparently I misunderstood. The issue is actually in `complex.jl` in base Julia? Shall I open an issue there?

Comment: Ah, one problem is the definition `float(x::Interval) = convert(Interval{Float64}, x)` in `ValidatedNumerics.jl`. This should respect `BigFloat`s.